# what is wrong with this code in settings.py file of my django application?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I am using Django 1.4 and Python 2.6 my operating system is Ubuntu 11.10. I am creating my Django app using these directories:

> project directory: /var/dj/oneliners/
>
> application directory: /var/dj/oneliners/oneline/

Now I want to serve my static directory for stylesheet so I configured `settings.py` as below:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/dj/oneliners/media/'

MEDIA_URL  = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/var/dj/oneliners/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/STATIC/'
```

I am unable to include my CSS in the `index.html` template when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/oneline/`. What am I doing wrong?

Hello and thanks in advance, here is my entire settings.py file:

```
# Django settings for oneliners project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'db_oneliner',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'admin@ubc7',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
import os.path
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "media") 

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "/var/dj/oneliners/static"
)
#ANONYMOUS_USER_ID = -1
# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '6h5dvw*-^hb=l*2v@sn15r36fy&amp;+mhv_+@#f=4az$-!()4hip_'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'oneliners.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'oneliners.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "/var/dj/oneliners/mytemplates",
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'oneline',
    'registration',
    'userena',
    'guardian',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
ANONYMOUS_USER_ID = -1
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'userena.backends.UserenaAuthenticationBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'oneline.MyProfile'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: can you add your whole settings.py

Comment: Hello have added my settings.py with os.path added to media root kindly let me know if there any thing wrong

Answer (score 1):

In development you have to add a specific URL pattern to your urls in `urls.py`.

The Django docs talk about this in detail [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development).

Note that you should **disable this url in production**. So enable the URL pattern only in development, by doing for instance:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0], 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

assuming the first [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-dirs) directory is the one containing your CSS (and other static files).

In production it is suggested to never serve static files via Django; do it via Apache or better, [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main).

Comment: yes this is the part of solution but i think his settings needs more modification like 
-------------
`STATIC_URL = os.path.join(SITE_URL, 'static/')`

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "media")

Comment: @jeevank You can put whatever you want as `document_root`, however I suggest using `settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0]` so that you can use `collectstatic` management command later on. Don't forget to mark the correct answer as *correct* :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, there is *no need* to specify `if settings.DEBUG:` and lines below it: [they are automatically loaded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) w/ `staticfiles` installed and `runserver` in DEBUG mode.

What you need to do is to make the `STATICFILES_FINDERS` to find the css file. For the two defined in you `settings.py`: `FileSystemFinder` searches dirs in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, `AppDirectoriesFinder` searches for the css in installed apps.

Thus, copy the file to `/var/dj/oneliners/static` or `some_installed_app/static` will do the trick.  Note that before you start to collect statics to `STATIC_ROOT`, you could simply leave `STATIC_ROOT=''`, and, `STATIC_ROOT` should be different from dirs defined in `STATICFILES_DIRS` (could contain) because they're different in logic.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your urlpatterns, it works for me 
(r'^css/(?P.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/xxx/WebRoot/css'}),