# How to attach CSS to my template?

Tags: html, css, django, templates

I'd like to attach css to my template in Django. I created static dir in the main folder of my project and in settings.py added these lines:

```
import os
ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path = lambda *a: os.path.join(ROOT, *a)
PROJECT = os.path.basename(ROOT)
```

Then I defined vars in settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = path('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = path('static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = path('static')
```

In template I link to css in a such way:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Django generates page with such source code:

```
<link href="/static/css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If I try to access this link (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/myss.css`) from Chrome source code viewer, it returns:

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is wrong with this code in settings.py file of my django application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410264/what-is-wrong-with-this-code-in-settings-py-file-of-my-django-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In development you have to add a specific URL pattern to your urls in `urls.py`.

The Django docs talk about this in detail [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development).

Note that you should **disable this url in production**. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10410498/1211429) to another, very similar question should help you fix this.

Comment: thank you! my problem was I didn't add ending slash in STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static/")